# Set a div to 'position fixed' in an Angular2 inner-component

Tags: css, html, angular, angular2-routing

I have a main component:

```
    <md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav>
        <md-nav-list>
            <a md-list-item *ngFor="let view of views">
                <md-icon md-list-icon>{{view.icon}}</md-icon>
                <div style="clear:right"></div>
                <div class="description-wrapper">
                    <span md-line>{{view.name}}</span>
                    <span md-line class="secondary">{{view.description}}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-toolbar *ngIf="!menuToolbarConfig.IsLoginView">
        <div (click)="menuToolbarConfig.goToApprovals()" class="goBack" *ngIf="menuToolbarConfig.IsDetailView">
            <md-icon>navigate_before</md-icon>
        </div>
        <button *ngIf="!menuToolbarConfig.IsDetailView" md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
            <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </button> {{menuToolbarConfig.ToolbarTitle}}
        <!--<button md-fab>
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
    </button>-->
    </md-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-layout>

<div style="background-color: red; height: 30px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px"></div>
```

As you can see I am using the official Angular2 material-framework. On every page the toolbar and the sidenav should appear, so I put the `<router-outlet>` in the `<md-sidenav-layout>`. Everything is fine, but now I want to create a snackbar that appears out of the bottom of the screen and should be fixed to the bottom. Now I have the problem, when I place the snackbar in a inner-component, that replaces the `<router-outlet>`, and I want to set the snackbar 'position: fixed' the snackbar would be correctly shown in the bottom of the page, but if I scroll, than the snackbar dont stay at the bottom instead its hovering over the bottom. But when I place a test div (last line) outside the `<md-sidenav-layout>` it works fine. So the problem is, that the fixed snackbar/div is within the `<md-sidenav-layout>`. But I need to have the snackbar in my inner-component.

My question now: Is there any smart solution to fix this problem, without a big workaround?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Yes I solved it with an injectable service, that manage all of my snackbars.